# rewrite relative or absolute path from inherited tramp ssh property with org-babel

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, tramp

I define a global remote session for all my sh block code with properties

```
:PROPERTIES
:HEADER-ARGS:bash: :dir /ssh:xxx@myvm:/home/xxx/
:END:
```

In my other bash blocks, I inherit this property, but after working folder was created, my code are executed in sub folder of `/home/xxx`

Here an example with creation of two folders in `/home/xxx` : `todolist1` and `todolist2`

I finally found that `noweb` is a good path to follow :

```
* Example
:PROPERTIES:
:HEADER-ARGS:bash: :dir /ssh:xxx@myvm:/home/xxx/
:END:

#+NAME: createdir
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :var folder="" :exports none
if [ -n "${folder}" ] ; then
    if [ -d "${folder}" ]; then
        rm -Rf "${folder}"
    fi
    mkdir "${folder}"
fi
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: gotodir
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :var folder="" :exports none
if [ -n "${folder}" ] ; then
    cd "${folder}"
fi
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC bash :var folder="todolist1" :noweb yes :exports both
<<createdir>>
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC bash :var folder="todolist2" :noweb yes :exports both
<<createdir>>
#+END_SRC

// First action on todolist 1
#+NAME: addmytodolist1
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :var folder="todolist1" :noweb yes :exports both :results verbatim
<<gotodir>>
cat > todolist1.org <<EOF 
#mytodolist
- [ ] item 1
- [X] item 2
EOF
#+END_SRC

// Second action on todolist 1
#+NAME: addmytodolist12
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :var folder="todolist1" :noweb yes :exports both :results verbatim
<<gotodir>>
cat >> todolist1.org <<EOF 
- [ ] item 3
EOF
#+END_SRC

// First action on todolist 2
#+NAME: addmytodolist2
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :var folder="todolist2" :noweb yes :exports both :results verbatim
<<gotodir>>
cat > todolist2.org <<EOF 
- [X] item 1
- [X] item 2
- [ ] item 3
- [X] item 4
EOF
#+END_SRC
```

To write less verbose and better maintainable code, i try without success :

- to hide the `<<gotodir>>` instruction from export using `:prologue <<gotodir>>` => failed
- I also try to directly expand `dir:` into header args, but that doesn't take in account the remote TRAMP ssh connexion : `#BEGIN_SRC sh :var folder="todolist1" :dir (expand-file-name (org-sbe "gotodir"))`
- I suppose it exist some elisp code to get TRAMP ssh folder, and rewrite it/overwrite it by using new url `{trampfolder}/todolist1` or `{trampfolder}/todolist2` ?

There are probably better and more robust way to do that, I'm interested to know what org-mode/org-babel guru :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use elisp in the `:dir` header to fetch the value the `:HEADER-ARGS:bash` from the `PROPERTIES` drawer, remove original `:dir` string and return new value with a subdirectory appended.

- For example, to append the `todolist1`, subdirectory, set the header below  on the bash code block.

  ```
  :dir (format "%s/todolist1" (replace-regexp-in-string ":dir +" "" (org-entry-get nil "HEADER-ARGS:bash" t)))
  ```

Below is an full example, which executes 3 bash code blocks via `tramp` in the default, `todolist1`, and `todolist2` directories.

```
* Example
:PROPERTIES:
:HEADER-ARGS:bash: :dir /ssh:xxx@myvm:/home/xxx
:END:

- The block below will execute in =/ssh:xxx@myvm:/home/xxx=, i.e. the default =:dir=

  #+BEGIN_SRC bash 
  echo "$USER@$HOSTNAME executed this block in the $PWD directory"
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
  : xxx@myvm executed this block in the /home/xxx directory

- The block below will execute in =/ssh:xxx@myvm:/home/xxx/todolist1=

  #+BEGIN_SRC bash :dir (format "%s/todolist1" (replace-regexp-in-string ":dir +" "" (org-entry-get nil "HEADER-ARGS:bash" t)))
    echo "$USER@$HOSTNAME executed this block in the $PWD directory"
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
  : xxx@myvm executed this block in the /home/xxx/todolist1 directory

- The block below will execute in =/ssh:xxx@myvm:/home/xxx/todolist2=

  #+BEGIN_SRC bash :dir (format "%s/todolist2" (replace-regexp-in-string ":dir +" "" (org-entry-get nil "HEADER-ARGS:bash" t)))
    echo "$USER@$HOSTNAME executed this block in the $PWD directory"
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
  : xxx@myvm executed this block in the /home/xxx/todolist2 directory
```

---

The `noweb` functionality built into org-mode is amazingly useful!

- Assign names to `SRC` blocks using `#+NAME:` or `:new-ref` headers.

  > e.g. `#+NAME: my-code` or `:noweb-ref my-code`
- `SRC` blocks with the same name become a single block when read in order from the top to bottom of the org file.
- Names provide 2 new features inside other `SRC` blocks with the `:noweb yes` header.

  - Use `<<my-code>>` syntax to automatically embed code from blocks named `my-code`.
  - Use `<<my-code()>>` syntax to execute blocks named `my-code` and automatically embed the `#+RESULTS:` generated by the named block. As extra bonus, you can pass variables in the the `()` to the named blocks before execution.
- Use the `:tangle` and `:file` headers to generate multiple files out and org file. As an added bonus, use `:mkdir yes` to automatically create missing subdirectories.
- Mix and match these features to generate source code, config files, images and other forms human documentation from an org-mode file. In the past, I have generated 100+ customized files to build a project from a single org file.

Thanks for asking your question!

---

> **The code in this answer was tested using:**
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)
>   org-mode version: 9.1.2

Comment: Thansk for your complete answer. You don't answer about noweb <<anyblockcode>> expansion into block headers arg (:prologue, :dir, etc.) so i suppose that's not possible actually ?

Comment: @reyman64 - To my knowledge, `<<anyblockcode>>` syntax can’t be used directly in block headers but it is possible to execute named code blocks in headers like this, `:var data=anyblockcode()` or like this `:dir (org-sbe anyblockcode)`. But it looks like you already knew this. Would you like me to update my answer?

Comment: @reyman64 - It is possible to create code blocks dynamically as the results from another code block. In that case you could use `<<anyblockcode>>` syntax in headers when the new blocks are rendered. Would you like me to update my answer?

Comment: If you have some times, i'm interested yes to see how you do that, because i try and failed using <<block>> in header. THanks